# How to fix code to make Burger navbar work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to make a burger navbar on a smaller screen. But it doesn't work, and instead of a burger I have that ugly button. What's wrong with my code?  I can't style it in CSS, it doesn't change the font even.

```css
.navbar * {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 18px;
  font-family: "Nunito";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="brand-page">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">S|K</a>

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">My Story</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Education</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Experience</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You should not be applying such heavy-handed CSS which styles _every_ element inside your navbar.

Comment: Please revise to explain your goals better. Bootstrap provides really nice navbars with dropdown menus for mobile out of the box. What's not working as you like?